# Why Spring doesn't have rollback methods in TransactionSynchronization interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

In Spring TransactionSynchronization interface it has methods (in order of execution):

```
- beforeCommit
- beforeCompletion
- afterCommit: Can perform further operations right after the main transaction has successfully committed. 
- afterCompletion
```

Why Spring doesn't have rollback methods, such as beforeRollback or afterRollback but it has for commit only (beforeCommit and afterCommit)? Will this is necessary? Can anyone give me some advices or explains about this?

If I want to continue further operations that are supposed to follow on a successful rollback of the main transaction, like notification messages or emails what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
                    @Override
                    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
                        if (status == TransactionSynchronization.STATUS_ROLLED_BACK) {
                            logger.trace("Rolled back...");
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Can I ask why you are using this interface?

This is used for callbacks by the PlatformTransactionManager which is in charge of managing the transaction lifecycle.

The "normal" use of Spring Transactions is to utilise `@Transactional`  annotations, aop declarations in xml or TransactionTemplate / PlatformTransactionManager programatically to set the transaction scope, behaviour and visibility, as described in the docs - [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction).

To manage a transaction behaviour for rollbacks etc you just tell spring what to do in the event of an Exception

```
public class Foo { 

   @Autowired public Service someService;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,
                   noRollbackFor = {IOException.class})
    public boolean bar(SomeObject someObject) throws IOException {
         someService.doComplicatedThing(someObject.getValue());
    }
}
```

This tells the `PlatformTransactionManager` to start a new TX when hitting the `foo()` method, commit on successful return or an IOException, and rollback if there is some other type of exception. This is the genius of it - you dont need to worry about littering your code with `getTransaction().isActive()` and complicated checks for managing the isolation.

Comment: I need this interface to ensure that whenever transaction commit or rollback success (status COMMITTED or ROLLED_BACK) I will trigger another proper action after that. I just wonder why just only have methods for commit (beforeCommit, afterCommit) but not for rollback. And is it necessary to have these methods? In case rollback success and I want to send message to notify I will implement this in afterCompletion method?

Comment: In Spring documentation: "afterCommit: Can perform further operations right after the main transaction has successfully committed. ". How about a successfully rolledback?

Comment: You can do that with the service class - call the method, if you get the result then it worked, if you get an Exception (say RuntimeException in the example above) then the rollback has been completed. Otherwise you are getting into the internals of the PlatformTransactionManager - eg implementing the the CallbackPreferringPlatformTransactionManager would give you the granularity and access to a callback on the given events but I've never come across a custom implementation like that

Comment: Just had another look at the interface spec for TransactionSynchronization - have you tried afterCompletion? The callback comes with a status that tells you the result commit, rollback etc

Comment: Yes. Currently I use afterCompletion callback to handle my task